# claymore: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: mining

Ethos rookie problem.

Running ethos 1.2.2.

uname -a
Linux d0c6fe 4.8.17-ethos38 #3 SMP Sun Apr 30 07:16:13 CDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Mining starts but there is a 0.0 hashrate.  Getting this error:

/opt/miners/claymore/claymore: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory

Here is the directory.

07:24 PM ethos@d0c6fe 192.168.1.112 [miner started] /opt/miners/claymore # ls
claymore     Data1b1.bin  Data1e1.bin  Data1g2.bin  dpools.txt     History.txt    start.bash
config.txt   Data1c1.bin  Data1e2.bin  Data3.bin    epools.txt     License.txt
Data1a1.bin  Data1d1.bin  Data1g1.bin  Data.bin     ethdcrminer64  Readme!!!.txt

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to get this rig going.

Comment: Hey Harold! Having the same issue, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Finally, yes.  I run ethminer using etherpool and pipe to a log. I use Geth to manage my eth accounts. I use etherpool to see my payouts. 

Geth does not see ethminer progress so I use the log to view operations history.

Comment: Ethos would not see nvidia cards.

Comment: So it works under EthOS with etherpool but not claymore even though EthOS doesn't see the nvidia cards?

Answer (score -1):

Try it to solve the problem
I had same problem and this App helped me to solve the issue.
It's dag error fixer.
Look at this youtube video:  https://youtu.be/G1zTIfFC-hg

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Per other feedback on your duplicate answers, you need to explain more.  Also, the executable you are running from the YouTube video might be very bad malware.  You probably should explain more why you think it is safe, before suggesting it to others.